# How to unify access to elements with ordinal id using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have several almost identical elements on the page. They differ only in their id - id="id1", id="id2", ..., id="id10"
I have a JQuery code that looks something like this:

```
$('.element #set1 .select').on('mouseleave', function(){
    if ($('.element #set1 .select .options:visible').length) {
    $('.element #set1 .select .options').slideUp('fast');
    $('.element #set1 .select a.value').addClass('selected').text('1');
}});
```

...

```
$('.element #set10 .select').on('mouseleave', function(){
    if ($('.element #set10 .select .options:visible').length) {
    $('.element #set10 .select .options').slideUp('fast');
    $('.element #set10 .select a.value').addClass('selected').text('1');
}});
```

Is there a way how to use only one unified code to access all sets with different ids?

Comment: Why not give them a common class?  That's kinda the purpose of classes.

Comment: What Html element is #set10? Please insert your html code of your selector in jquery for a better understand. (Including .element and all his childs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use current element context i.e. `this` in the event handler, it refers to element which invoked the event and use various DOM traversal method i.e. [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target current element dependents

```
$('#set1, #set2, ..., #set10 ').on('mouseleave', '.select', function () {
    if ($(this).find('.options:visible').length) {
        $(this).find('.options').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).find('a.value').addClass('selected').text('1');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your way but what to do in this case? `$('.element #set1 .select .options a').on('click', function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $('.element #set1 .select .options a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.element #set1 .select .options').slideUp('fast');
        $('.element #set1 .select a.value').addClass('selected').text(text);
        return false;
    });`